# How to restart "TabletInputService" on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, services

I want to restart this service "`TabletInputService`" on **windows 10  22H2 64bit**

I have tried :

```
net stop TabletInputService 



The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.
```

also, I have tried this and didn't work:

```
taskkill /fi "Services eq TabletInputService" /F



ERROR: The process with PID 1636 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

[Taskmanger include TabletInputService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuQev.jpg)

Comment: I can use the "taskkill" command but I need admin access, 

is there a workaround without give the admin permission?

Comment: I have found "svchost.exe" have the same "PID number" as "TabletInputService", maybe this causes some issues?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Question: Do you have a tablet or at least a touch screen?

Comment: yes, I have a display tablet with a pen but no touchscrean, seems I need admin right to kill because I use a user with admin privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD as Admin:

`sc stop TabletInputService`

This command will attempt to stop the `"TabletInputService"` using the `Service Control Manager (SCM)`.

If the above command doesn't work, you can try changing the permissions of the service:

`sc sdset TabletInputService D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)`

This command will grant full permissions to the System, Administrators, Interactive Users, and Service Users groups for the "TabletInputService".

After changing the permissions, try stopping the service using the following command:

`net stop TabletInputService`

If this command still doesn't work, you can try killing the service process using Task Manager. find the `"TabletInputService.exe"` process and `end task` it.

Comment: thank you ^^, sadly I changed the Service permission (cmd as admin), and tried both "sc stop" and "net stop" methods and both of them won't work unfortunately. 

only thing I found it's "taskkill" with admin right.

Comment: I have found "svchost.exe" have the same "PID number" as "TabletInputService", maybe this causes some issues?